# default proposals in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, default

I forked a branch from git into my local repository and I am unable to get the default proposals using Ctrl+Space.

Tried Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced and checked Java proposal or Java non-type proposal.
Still doesn't work. 
How do I get the default proposals to work?

Comment: why do you think that your problem is related to git? Does content assist stop working right after 'git branch'?